# Error in using MSAL library to authenticate users in azure b2c and unprotected resources

Tags: angular, angular8, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I m using MSAL 1.3 to authenticate Azure B2C users in my Angular 8 app which has .net core back end API. It all works great except when a user is not logged in, we get an error when trying to call an unprotected end point in my webapi to register new users. The call is made in a serivce class (service.ts) and the error I get say's

> MSAL Logging:  Thu, 18 Jun 2020 16:21:19 GMT:2335b876-d867-4b1f-9d3f-d285caa0ee04-1.3.0-Error Error when acquiring token for scopes: https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint
>   mycomponent.component.ts:132 ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint

The API its trying to reach has been added as `unprotectedResources` and MSAL should not try to get token silently and check if the User is logged in.

My b2c config looks like below

```
import { Configuration } from 'msal';
import { MsalAngularConfiguration } from '@azure/msal-angular';

// this checks if the app is running on IE
export const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: "b2c_1_susi",
        resetPassword: "b2c_1_reset",
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi"
        },
        resetPassword: {
            authority: "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_reset"
        } 
    }
}


export const apiConfig: {b2cScopes: string[], webApi: string} = {
    b2cScopes: ['https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read'],
    webApi: 'https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello'
};


export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "e760cab2-b9a1-4c0d-86fb-ff7084abd902",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:6420/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:6420/",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        validateAuthority: false,
      },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set this to "true" to save cache in cookies to address trusted zones limitations in IE
    },
}


export const loginRequest: {scopes: string[]} = {
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
};

// Scopes you enter will be used for the access token request for your web API
export const tokenRequest: {scopes: string[]} = {
    scopes: apiConfig.b2cScopes // i.e. [https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read]
};


export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
    [apiConfig.webApi, apiConfig.b2cScopes] // i.e. [https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello, ['https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read']]
];


export const msalAngularConfig: MsalAngularConfiguration = {
    popUp: !isIE,
    consentScopes: [
        ...loginRequest.scopes,
        ...tokenRequest.scopes,
    ],
    unprotectedResources: ["https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/api/register"], // API calls to these coordinates will NOT activate MSALGuard
    protectedResourceMap,     // API calls to these coordinates will activate MSALGuard
    extraQueryParameters: {}  
}
```

My app module looks like below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

import { Configuration } from 'msal';
import {
  MsalModule,
  MsalInterceptor,
  MSAL_CONFIG,
  MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
  MsalService,
  MsalAngularConfiguration
} from '@azure/msal-angular';

import { msalConfig, msalAngularConfig } from './app-config';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return msalConfig;
}

function MSALAngularConfigFactory(): MsalAngularConfiguration {
  return msalAngularConfig;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatListModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
      useFactory: MSALAngularConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to their documentation `As of @azure/msal-angular@1.1.0, protectedResourceMap supports wildcard patterns that are supported by minimatch, and unprotectedResources is deprecated and ignored.`

Instead put `protectedResourceMap: null` should work

Reference: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2217

Answer (score 0):

It works when the unprotected resources array contains list of all the end points including individual routes e.g.

Just adding the following Url does not work

`https://some-webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Home/`

However the following does work

`https://some-webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Home/HelloGet`

`https://some-webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Home/HelloPost`

Answer (score 0):

### MSAL_CONFIG configuration object:

When you are configuring MSAL in the framework object you can use unprotectedResources to add a list of strings that will be the urls of the unprotected endpoints.

```
{
    auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientId,
        authority: environment.authorityUrl,
        validateAuthority: false,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: postLogoutUri
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    },
    framework: {
        unprotectedResources: [
            `====> YOUR_ENDPOINT_UTL <====`,
            'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/',
            './assets/i18n'
        ],
        protectedResourceMap: new Map(protectedResourceMap)
    }
};
```

### Why doesn't it work for you?

It's not working for you because you're configuring it in the wrong place (or things have changed, I'm working with msal 1.3.0). **You are configuring the unprotected URLs in the MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR configuration and not in MSAL_CONFIG**.

## Final score:

I share the final result of my module to show my configuration of MSAL_CONFIG and MSAL_ANGULAR_CONFIG

```
export function createTranslateRootLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
// Changelog service
export function app_Init(changelogHttpService: ChangelogHttpService) {
    return () => changelogHttpService.initializeApp();
}

// MSAL params
export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
    ['https://login.microsoftonline.com/Sorry_I_can't_show_this/', ['user.read']]
];

export function postLogoutUri() {
    return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/home';
}

export function getConfig() {
    return {
        auth: {
            clientId: environment.clientId,
            authority: environment.authorityUrl,
            validateAuthority: false,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: postLogoutUri
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false
        },
        framework: {
            unprotectedResources: [
                `${environment.base_url}/mip/company/ <== My new endpoint`,
                'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/',
                './assets/i18n'
            ],
            protectedResourceMap: new Map(protectedResourceMap)
        }
    };
}

export function getConfigAngular() {
    return {
        popUp: false,
        consentScopes: ['user.read', 'openid', 'profile', `api://${environment.clientId}/access_as_user`],
        extraQueryParameters: {}
    };
}

// Init
export function initApp(app: InitService) {
    return () => app.init();
}

 @ NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CoreModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        // Translate module configure
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateRootLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        // MSAL configure
        MsalModule,
        // Notifier configure
        NotifierModule.withConfig(customNotifierOptions)
    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [
        MsalService,
        BroadcastService, {
            provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
            useValue: getConfig()
        }, {
            provide: MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
            useValue: getConfigAngular()
        }, {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: BypassInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }, {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MsalInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }, {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }, {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpSuccessInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }, {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initApp,
            deps: [InitService],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```